# Rails 4 get column names in raw activerecord query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
query = <<-EOF
        select player_id, first_name, last_name,
            max(case when site_id = 1 then salary end) fd_salary,
            max(case when site_id = 2 then salary end) dd_salary,
            max(case when site_id = 3 then salary end) ss_salary,
            max(case when site_id = 4 then salary end) ds_salary,
            max(case when site_id = 7 then salary end) dk_salary,
            max(case when site_id = 8 then salary end) elite_salary
            from player_salaries ps
            where ps.gamedate = '2014-05-25'
            and sport_id = #{$MLB_SPORT_ID}
            group by player_id
    EOF

        salaries = PlayerSalary.connection.execute(query)
```

The problem is `salaries` in this case comes back as an array with values. These query is a bit complex and the names I'm using such as `fd_salary`, `dd_salary` and so forth aren't physical attributes in the `PlayerSalary` model. There's no way to do something like `salaries.first.fd_salary`. Is there a way to change the above in Rails 4 to get it access values by column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql) for this:

> **find_by_sql(sql, binds = [])**
>
> Executes a custom SQL query against your database and returns all the results. The results will be returned as an array with columns requested encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method from. If you call `Product.find_by_sql` then the results will be returned in a `Product` object with the attributes you specified in the SQL query.

So if you did:

```
salaries = PlayerSalary.find_by_sql(query)
```

then you could say things like `salaries.first.fd_salary`. Just don't try to use columns that weren't in your query or try to change the returned `PlayerSalary` objects and expect anything useful to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve your records as a hash, with column names you can use mysql2 adapter directly with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get('@connection').query("SELECT * FROM `users`", as: :hash).first
```

I was searching for another way to do it but had no luck.